# GridView item layout not show image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have next GridView layout that I am inflating from their adapter. I am showing the layout and the title but I can't see the image. Anyway I see the blank space in the screen. Any idea?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_normal"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Title of the Item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/titleButton"
        tools:text="Title of the Item"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show please some code of your Adapter.

Comment: post your adapter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have added **AppCompat library** in gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
```

Becuase `app:srcCompat`attribute is actually defined within **AppCompat library**.

You can use `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` to avoid seeing error temporarily.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_normal"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
```

Try to use **AppCompatImageView**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you add more info about this? This worked, but I liked know why :S